# Simple math in a String using java

Tags: java, android, math

This is what I have :

```
final EditText Pikkus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
final EditText Laius = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
final TextView pindala1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final TextView ymbermoot1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
ImageButton button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.teisenda);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String pindala2 = "" + Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString());
            pindala1.setText(pindala2);
        String ymbermoot2 = "" + Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString())
        ymbermoot1.setText(ymbermoot2);

    }
});
```

But the

```
String ymbermoot2 = ""
        + Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString())
        + Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString());

ymbermoot1.setText(ymbermoot2);
```

part doesn't work like its supposed to. Instead of adding up the values, it simply types them together. Example: integer Pikkus is 26, Laius is 23. The value should end up being 49, but my code somehow makes it to up to be 2623. Where's the mistake in the code?

Comment: It first adds the `""` and the first `int`. Surround your integer addition with `( )`

Comment: you start with `""+` so all the following `+` are treated like a `String` concatination. If you want to use them for the `Integer` us paranthesis.

Comment: @Reimeus 5 bugs in 9 lines?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
String ymbermoot2 = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString()));
```

Comment: If you want short lines...
int aux = Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString());
int aux2 = Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString());
String ymbermoot2 = Integer.toString(aux+aux2);

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
String ymbermoot2 = "" + (Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString())
+ Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString()))
```

It will help.

Answer (score 1):

That's what happens when you try to write as little lines as possible, and it's so wrong. Of course - number of lines determines good code but not always. So I would split it into few lines:

```
int someNumber = Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString());
int someOtherNumber = Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString());
String pindala2 = String.valueOf(someNumber * someOtherNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String pindala2 = "" + (Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are concatenating strings instead of adding or multiplying them up because you cannot make arithmetic operations on strings . Try following code :

```
 String pindala2 = ""+Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) * Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString())));
```

Here we are first we multiply two integers and then converting it to String.

Comment: Thank you! Got it!

Answer (score 0):

```
int value =  Integer.parseInt(Pikkus.getText().toString()) + Integer.parseInt(Laius.getText().toString())
```